# 2D plot of X,Y,Z array

Tags: matlab, plot, contour

I trying to create a 2D contoured plot of a three column array

column 1 is an X position
column 2 is a Y position
column 3 is the corresponding electric field strength (Z) at that coordinate

Contour(X,Y,Z) is not working I get this message:

Z must be size 2x2 or greater.

Can you help???

Comment: Read [contour](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/contour.html) documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Z is a n by m matrix containing the z values.
X is a one dimensional matrix of size n containing the x values.
Y is a one dimensional matrix of size m containg the y values.
Z (i,  j) contains the z value corresponding to X(i) and Y(j)

Answer (score 0):

Do your X's and Y's repeat?

eg:

```
 X Y Z
 0 0 1
 0 1 2
 1 0 3
 1 1 4
```

If so, you can rearrange into axis vectors X and Y, and Matrix Z:

```
 X
 0
 1

 Y
 0
 1

 Z
 1 3
 2 4
```

Otherwise, you could just interpolate onto a grid that does repeat.

```
 x = [0 1];
 y = [0 1];
 z = [1 3 ; 2 4];
 contour(x,y,z)
```